# Allow an author of a comment to see their comment listed in the comment section of a node with a notice that the comment is in moderation?

Tags: 7, comments

I seem to be getting a lot of duplicate comments on my site and I think it has to do with the fact that users do not see their comment right after submitting it. I have it set so that an admin must approve it before it is published. Is there any way to make it so the user can only see his own comment on the node before it is published with a little notice that tells them it is in moderation?